# Upgrade to 18.04.01 from 16.04 LTS... Login but no Gnome Gui

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04, lts

Wondering if others are having issues getting 18.04.01 from 16.04 LTS up and running.  I just upgraded via the terminal.  I am able to login to my machine, but it hangs at the wallpaper/splash screen.  I cannot do anything without the Gui I am too newbie.  Suggestions?   Thanks!

Note: one attempt to launch in recovery mode ended with the same result.

PARTIAL ANSWER: Running sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop got the 18.04.01 GUI up and running but I have issues on my HP dm4 Pavilion such as internet connection is broken on GUI and terminal.  GUI sees possible connections but 'Connect' is disabled and grayed-out. Terminal had been able to connect before running "...reinstall ubuntu-desktop".Thank you to @Eliah Kagan & @Radu Rădeanu for posting:  [Reinstalling Ubuntu via Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434635/reinstalling-ubuntu-via-terminal)  And @lzzy88 for posting:  [Restore Ubuntu 16.04 without losing files and settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802385/restore-ubuntu-16-04-without-losing-files-and-settings)

Comment: In my opinion Ubuntu tries to stick to the settings prior to the upgrade. So technically it may be sticking to unity. And during upgrade unity may have been broken. Try getting into tty mode and installing gnome.

Comment: CTRL ALT F1 ( held long & short ) got no response from the machine.

Comment: TTY can be achieved by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F? where ? can vary from 1-7. In 18.04 combo with F1 and F2 is reserved for GUI. Try another function key.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Per your question:  it's old but: https://askubuntu.com/questions/403747/how-to-access-gui-from-tty-mode  I'm trying other Fkeys but it occasionally reboots in low graphics mode.  Switching between GNOME options at the login screen using the Ubuntu icon repeatedly asks for my login, accepts it, then loops back to the login.  F3&4 give me a prompt but no shell.... Super newbie here...  I have to go soon.

Comment: This might help https://askubuntu.com/a/789353/816190

Comment: Do you have working internet?

Comment: If yes try this: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` `sudo apt update` `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop` `sudo reboot now`. Then try changing desktop environment from login screen.

Comment: I have working Internet, but since login is looping I can't get my computer to see the Internet.

Comment: Have you tried the answer in the link I've posted above? you can try `ping` to check whether internet is working or not

Comment: I can't post my screenshot, but I have a successful ping, and the first command sudo apt-add-repository...  Returns:  "...version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libpkg-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference"

Comment: sudo apt install lightdm Returned:  Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages ( or specify a solution ).    Example code here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032838/after-upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-changed-from-terminal-to-gui  Wondering if I should follow this code or look for updates via Software Updater.

Comment: @CMartin and did you run `sudo apt-get install -f`?  If so what was its output?

Comment: RECAP: Attempting to install GNOME Vanilla & full resulted in: Unmet dependencies, install -f.  Updates sudo apt update && sudo apt -y dist-upgrade Resulted in the same: install -f

Comment: -f install Results:  dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/use/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.system1.service' with different file '/use/share...  ...service.systemd', not allowed.  >>dpkg: error processing package systemd-shim (--remove):  >>installed systemd-shim package post-removal script us process returned error exit 2 status

Comment: (Above is supposed to say ...script subprocess returned error exit status 2)   >>>>Continued... >>Errors were encountered while processing:  >>systemd-shim. >>E:  Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code  (1)  >>>>Question: Would this be a smart next move?  exec sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean    https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032838/after-upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-changed-from-terminal-to-gui

Comment: cat /etc/lsb-release  Returns: 18.04.01.  Thank you Kulfy and Thomas Ward for your help. Is silence telling me I am out of luck?

Comment: Trying Dave's Method 1 did not work ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032126/upgraded-to-18-04-and-now-have-many-broken-packages-and-unmet-dependencies. Pasted below - thanks Dave! ).  I am considering Dave's method 2 but I need to understand how to recognize what packages to install, maybe a command list and a reference for what those commands are supposed to do to move forward with Aptitude in Method 2.  
Open a Terminal and type in:

sudo apt-get install -f
and press ENTER.

Now type in:

sudo dpkg --configure -a
and press ENTER.

Now one more time:

sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: This https://askubuntu.com/questions/838491/systemd-shim-error-after-upgrading-from-16-04-to-16-10 Returns: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f   How many might I uninstall Python in this situation?  Everything I'm finding is old.  It's look like at least part of the problem... Suggestions?

Comment: This is the error code I am getting:  https://qiita.com/miyagaw61/items/665616d769f74158f1a1   One exception:  everywhere this link says "ModuleNotFoundError" I have an "Import Error" with a full file location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PARTIAL ANSWER: Running sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop got the 18.04.01 GUI up and running but I have issues on my HP dm4 Pavilion such as internet connection is broken on GUI and terminal.  GUI sees possible connections but 'Connect' is disabled and grayed-out. Terminal had been able to connect before running "...reinstall ubuntu-desktop". Thank you to @Eliah Kagan & @Radu Rădeanu for posting: [Reinstalling Ubuntu via Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434635/reinstalling-ubuntu-via-terminal)  And @lzzy88 for posting: [Restore Ubuntu 16.04 without losing files and settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802385/restore-ubuntu-16-04-without-losing-files-and-settings)

Comment: The rest of the solution is here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071252/no-internet-after-16-04-lts-18-04-01-upgrade#comment1757327_1071252     ---Thank you Dr Chili555!!!!!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` did not work for me.