# Login problem after upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: upgrade, login

The GUI lets me select one of my (two) users at start-up, then skips to the screen where I should enter the corresponding password. However as soon as that screen pops up it shows the message "authentication failed" (even before I can enter a password) and after 1 or 2 seconds the systems skips to what looks like terminal mode on the screen showing the processes it started up, the last one being "[OK] Started PackageKit Daemon" and remains stuck there.

I can login via terminal mode instead of via GUI. I added an extra user via terminal mode. That all seems to work fine, but that doesn't solve the GUI problem. 
Who can help me out?

Comment: what do you see when you run command `tail -n 20 /var/log/syslog`?

Comment: I am a bit of a layman in Ubuntu, so please correct me if I don't provide the information you asked for. Prior to selecting a user at login the content of the log file seems okay.

Comment: No worry. have you try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`? 
[someone also has similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065485/upgrade-to-18-04-01-from-16-04-lts-login-but-no-gnome-gui?rq=1)

Comment: I think I entered my answer not in the correct way. It is displayed above your question concerning the content of the syslog file

Comment: would you mind enter all those terrifying news here? It seems like reinstalling gdm3 might fix the problem but it's worth looking into the error messages. I was wondering if lightdm is still installed on your system as well.

Comment: Any suggestions how to make a screen-copy from terminal mode? Copying the lines one by one might take a day.

Comment: I tried your suggestion "sudo apt-get install --restall ………." but the internet connection doesn't work anymore since the update, so the effect is limited.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit of a layman in Ubuntu, so please correct me if I don't provide the information you asked for. Prior to selecting a user at login the content of the log file seems okay. After that (and extending the 20 you mentioned to 60) it shows                /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5392]: (WW) xf86OpenConsole: VT_ACTIVATE failed: Operation not permitted        followed by  "Fatal server error" and "xf86OpenConsole: Switching VT failed"    followed by more terrifying news  where  gdm3 seems to be the common denominator.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and for your interest in this site.  However, your post does not answer the question that was asked and so should not be posted as an answer.   Since you are clarifying your original question you should simply edit your question and add the new information.